# why wont this simple todo list work in angular

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/jNEPaZcVIdzCrqUpO0PF?p=preview

Ive been playing around with this for a while and cant seem to spot qhy data binding/ ect isnt working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ng-app="myApp" on the html tag.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qi9L8JKtJE3o8WnWgca2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

`<html ng-app"myAppz">`

`angular.module('myApp', [])`

`myAppz` should be equal to `myApp`, otherwise the angular application cannot be initilized.

Comment: This still won't work, you will need to write `ng-app="myApp"` (Note the equal.)